# How can I encode string with http web request?

Tags: c#, .net, url, url-encoding

I need to send a string to a website and get back a result.

But for example if i send "hello world" it should be "hello%world" instead of space there should be a %

There should be a way i think to make it automatic so it will know where how and when to put this % when the string have spaces in this location.

For example i have this string which is a site url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
```

There is a %20 between the hello and the world. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method to build a properly encoded query string:

```
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
values["key"] = "INSERT-YOUR-KEY";
values["q"] = "hello world";
string queryString = values.ToString();
// at this stage queryString="key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello+world"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode:

`string s = "Hello World";`
`string t = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s);//t becomes "Hello+World"`